# django-rest-auth throws error with URL versioning

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

Using [Django Rest Auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) for authentication in my DRF based app. Issue is, the logout URL does not work when I add URL versioning.

Calling: `/v1/rest-auth/logout/` (POST)

Throws error: `TypeError: post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'`

**urls.py:**

```
URL_VERSION = r'^(?P<version>v[1])'
url(f'{URL_VERSION}/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls'))
```

Other end-points e.g. login via `/v1/rest-auth/login/` works okay with and without the URL_VERSION.

What could I be missing?

Comment: On the second line, are you actually using `url(f` or is that just a typo here?

Comment: Its actually an `f`. Its from python3.6 `f strings`. Link: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html. Example implementation is here: https://github.com/limdauto/drf_openapi/blob/master/examples/examples/urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed recently.

https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/pull/373

The new version will be on pypi very shortly. Please pull the master branch version for now if possible.

Comment: Thanks. Seen that. Had also raised an issue on github so will also close it.